# Removing element from priority queue

Tags: java, servlets, priority-queue

I'm trying to pass input from a servlet to my backend, and remove object from queue if the information matches.

segment from webpage where user inputs name of project they want to delete
below is where it reads the input then attempts to send the data to a back-end java file which is holding my priority queue

this section is aimed at reading in input from a form then that form calls processDeleteJobs which is called readdeletejobs above.

Readin in the deletejobs input, set my jobrequest element to testdelete then I send it off to a function in the back end

```
public boolean deleteJobFrontEnd(JobRequest job) {
boolean remove;
remove = scheduledJobs.remove().equals(job.getProjectName());
return remove;
}
```

The aim is to remove a jobrequest in the priorityqueue if a certain criteria matches
so if projectname within that jobrequest is matched then remove from queue
Also unsure on my boolean implementation whether this will remove it correctly or not.

very much a novice as you can see

Comment: What type of class is `scheduledJobs`?

Comment: PriorityQueue< JobRequest> scheduledJobs = new PriorityQueue<JobRequest>(100, comparator);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove it by calling [`PriorityQueue.remove(Object obj)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public boolean deleteJobFrontEnd(JobRequest job) {
    return scheduledJobs.remove(job);
}
```

Also, make sure `JobRequest` has `equals()` implemented correctly.

Or use an iterator:

```
Iterator it = scheduledJobs.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    if(sameJob(it.next())) // Implement sameJob 
        it.remove();
}
```

Comment: fails to remove job, is it because I'm only inputting information for an element of the job and trying to remove it that way? instead of all the job elements

Comment: Yes, or you must iterate through and find it, then delete it